# proper disposal of EF DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

The situation: 
I'm importing a lot of xlsx files into a mysql database, and I want to use EF6 for that. Connection works, I can import. However, something goes wrong and I feel that I'm missing a vital part.

```
class Importer
{
    public string ImportExcercise(C_patient patient, C_excercise excercise, List<C_breath> breaths, int PatientHasMultipleExercises)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbentries = new bxbEntities())
            {                     
                if (PatientHasMultipleExercises == 0)
                {
                    dbentries.C_patient.Add(patient);
                    dbentries.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Added Patient...");
                }                   
                excercise.C_patientID = patient.C_patientID;
                dbentries.C_excercise.Add(excercise);                    
                dbentries.SaveChanges();
                int exerid = excercise.C_excerciseID;
                Console.WriteLine("Added Excercise...");
                int i = 0;
                foreach (C_breath b in breaths)
                {
                    b.C_excerciseID = exerid;
                    dbentries.C_breath.Add(b);                      
                    Console.WriteLine("Added BxB record {0}...", i);
                    i++;
                }
                dbentries.SaveChanges();                    
            }
            return "import success!";
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                            validationError.PropertyName,
                                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm calling this converter like this:

```
public string StrokePatientExecFolder(string Folder)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Folder);
        int i = 0;

        while (i<files.Length)
        {

            if (!((File.GetAttributes(files[i]) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden))
            {
                xlsdata data = new xlsdata();
                Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", files[i]);
                data.xlsread(files[i]);
                StrokePatientConverter(data);
                Importer imp = new Importer();
                imp.ImportExcercise(p, e, b, i);
                b.Clear();
                i++;
            }

        }

        return "converted!";
    }
```

So this is what goes wrong: The first time all is well. When the 2nd file is imported (or at least the breaths) they are added to the previous set of breaths existing in the dbentries. I clarify: the first xlsx contains 250 breaths - they get imported. the second file contains 300 breaths -> 550 breaths are imported, all with the same excerciseID.

What I have tried so far: 
1) I tried to call dbentries.Dispose(); but I found out that is redundant because of the 'using-block'. 
2) First, Importer imp = new Importer(); was globally declared. Then I declared it locally, in each iteration of the while loop to ensure the object would be empty. To my surprise, it is not. 
3) I added a watch on dbentries. 
1st iteration: dbentries.C_breath -> before foreach loop -> Count = 0. After the foreach loop -> count = 250. 
2nd iteration: dbentries.C_breath -> before foreach loop -> Count = 250 (how is this possible? The DBContext should be disposed?). After the foreach loop -> count = 550.

I feel that I'm missing something basic here. This is my first EF6 project... Hope you guys can help me out!

added the model as requested
[image]

Comment: Can you post your model? If all items are being imported with the same "key" (if it is excerciseID, I am guessing) then I would bet you had not used "[key]" on your model, ie, [Key] public int excerciseID { get; set; }. Thay will create a key column.

Comment: there is a patient which is unique. 
a patient can have multiple exercises. Every exercise has a unique ID, and is linked to the patient with the patientID.
every breath is unique, but linked to the exercise with exerciseID